# MySQL Query slowed down when using OR operator

Tags: mysql

As my private message database has begun to grow, i'm noticing some considerable slow downs on the following query.

**The Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM privatemessages WHERE sender='940' OR recipient='940' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1000;
```

(The 940 can be any userid)

**The Table:**

```
   CREATE TABLE `privatemessages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `recipient` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sender` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `readstatus` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `messagetype` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rdeleted` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sdeleted` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `recipient` (`recipient`),
  KEY `sender` (`sender`),
  KEY `read` (`readstatus`),
  KEY `time` (`time`),
  KEY `openmessagingpanel` (`recipient`,`readstatus`),
  KEY `openpmthreadrev` (`recipient`,`sender`),
  KEY `openpmthread` (`sender`,`recipient`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8650153 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**MySQL Explain:**

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table           | type        | possible_keys                                                    | key              | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                                      |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | privatemessages | index_merge | recipient,sender,openmessagingpanel,openpmthreadrev,openpmthread | sender,recipient | 4,4     | NULL | 26100 | Using union(sender,recipient); Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------------+-------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Does anyone know what I need to do to get this query back up to speed? There is roughly 8 million records.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you really need to fetch all the fields for the rows you found (`SELECT *`) ?

Comment: Have you defined another index on this table that is combined for sender and recipient?  When I just take your table definition I get a much cleaner explain plan:

Comment: Sorry, I had messed up my copy and pastes. The original post has been corrected with how the database is now, although it is pretty messed up from testing some things out earlier today.

Answer (score 0):

2 thoughts:

- Is it worth creating a view for the messages with undeleted status, and selecting the messages from there, on the assumption there'll be less recs to deal with.
- Being verbose about SELECT-ing the fields you need usually yields a performance gain

Answer (score 0):

You allready have an Index on the sender and receiver column.

Assuming you need the request for the GUI where the user can select a message to read:

If you would only select id, title and maybe the time this would be enough for displaying the links to the messages. as well you can set limit to 50 or so and do some pageination.

or do you need it for some kind of export? then you should rather use the export functionality of mysql ...

hope this helps you.